# Is there a simplify of doing this Linq Query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linqpad

I am doing a query against a collection with a complex object

```
Movies
.Where(qry => qry.Delivery.Any(b => (b.DeliveryType.Contains("Digital"))))
.Select(qry => new { Id          = qry.Id, 
                     Name        = qry.Name, 
                     Description = qry.Description, 
                     Delivery    = qry.Delivery.Where(qry2 => qry2.DeliveryType.Contains("Digital")).FirstOrDefault()
                   }).ToArray().Where(qry => qry.Delivery.Properties.Any(d => d.Value == "UHD" || d.Value == "FHD" ||  d.Value == "HD"))
```

The movie catalog has two types, physical and digital and since I am interested in obtaining all movies that have the digital version I am running the above query and from the result set, I want to exlude the SD version of the digital.

Is there a way that I can execute this linq query without applyting the filtering from the result set?
I mean I would like to move the second where statement to be on my first one, so the query/filtering can be run agains the oData Webservice.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you're trying to do this:

```
Movies
   .Where(movie => movie.Delivery.Any(d => d.DeliveryType.Contains("Digital") 
       && d.Properties.Any(p => p.Value.EndsWith("HD"))))
```